# How do I use HTML Imports in a multi-view angular dart app?

Tags: dart, polymer, angular-dart, web-component

So I'm trying to use Polymer and Core Elements with Angular.dart and I'm running into a problem importing the HTML. The import statements need to be within the head tag, but I don't want to shove every import into the index.html.

Is there a way to add the imports/modify the header within each template?

Answer (score 1):

you can make a import.html file for example and fill it with your app imports then import  just that 1 file in the head of your app to keep from having hundreds of imports in the head.

i don't know if any methods for injecting headers work though.